# Texture Image Material is flipping the PNG file I Input

Tags: texturing, image

Here is an image of my Blender workspace:

[image]

As you can see, the image of the Spanish flag is flipped state on my plane.

Have I missed something here? All I did was add an image to the plane.

Is there a way to add another image on the opposite of the flag too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want it to look right from this side, there's a few quick solutions for that:

- Rotate the plane 180° around the Z-Axis
- Flip the texture by inverting the value under Mapping > Scale > X
- UV-Unwrap it from the side you're looking from with <kbd>U</kbd> > Project from view (bounds) (you might have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>  before).

If you want it to look right from both sides, you will have to duplicate the plane, offset it a tiny bit and unwrap both sides accordingly. But it's very rare that flags look correct from both sides, because printing that without the other side being visible is difficult.

Answer (score 8):

You're probably looking at the "back" of the plane, then.

To fix this, pick any one of the below options:

- **Mirror the plane on the X-axis.** Do this with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- **Flip the plane's normals.** Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter Edit Mode, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices, and then look in the tool shelf at left for *Flip Direction* under the *Normals* subheading (it's about halfway down the list).
- **Flip your camera around.** Put the 3D cursor at the center of the scene, change the pivot point to *3D Cursor* by pressing <kbd>. (period)</kbd>, and press <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>180</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
- **Create a UV map.** This is probably the best and most flexible solution, but it requires a little more work. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter Edit Mode, select all the vertices with <kbd>A</kbd>, and, since it's only a plane, simply press <kbd>U</kbd> and select *Unwrap*. Then, in the UV/Image Editor, you can move the UV vertices to make your texture display correctly.

Answer (score -1):

In the UV editor, press the mouse by the cube, press 'R' and type in 180.